# android - showDialog(); error

Tags: android

I trying to write if else condition for wifi connection but it throwing error.

Logcat

```
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355): Activity com.smartmenu.SplashActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41813bd0 that was originally added here
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.smartmenu.SplashActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41813bd0 that was originally added here
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:343)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:245)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at com.smartmenu.SplashActivity.showDialog(SplashActivity.java:205)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at com.smartmenu.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:93)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-04 13:32:51.227: E/WindowManager(4355):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code

```
  if(str.equals(""))
        {                          
           ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);    
        if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity.*/ 
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
        }
        else
        {                   
            showDialog();
        }
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);    
            if (mWifi.isConnected()) {                  
                  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity.*/ 
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                        SplashActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
                new DownloadFilesTask().execute();
            }
            else
            {                   
                showDialog();
            }
```

showDialog();

```
  private void showDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Attention");
        dialog.setMessage("No Internet Connection. Please enable the wifi. ");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new 
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                int whichButton) 
                {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity.*/ 
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                        SplashActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
                }
            });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: can you post your code where you getting error?

Comment: the code that generates this error would be helpfull at helping you

Comment: You are failing to pass proper context to your dialog.

Comment: usually i have to ask for the logcat output on stackoverflow... it's weird having to ask for the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using AsyncTask and display your dialog in onPostExecute. In onPreExecute display your splashscreen.

Comment: Did  you get the solutions using this?

Answer (score 0):

**You're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.**

The solution is to call dismiss() on the Dialog you created before exiting the Activity, e.g. in onPause().

Views have a reference to their parent Context (taken from constructor argument). If you leave an Activity without destroying Dialogs and other dynamically created Views, they still hold this reference to your Activity (if you created with this as Context: like new ProgressDialog(this)), so it cannot be collected by the GC, causing a memory leak.

original answer is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added) by Alex